# How to change audio recording settings to 16Khz and 16 bit when we record audio?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, audio-recording

I have the settings shown below.

I want change audio recording settings to 16Khz and 16 bit when we record audio.

```
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                               NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                           stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.wav"];

NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary
                                dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                                AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
                                AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0],
                                AVSampleRateKey,
                                nil];

NSError *error = nil;

audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                 initWithURL:soundFileURL
                 settings:recordSettings
                 error:&error];

if (error)
{

} else
{
    [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
}
```

How to set those settings?

**Edit the question**:

Thanks for giving the replies, i tried those ways but it did not work for me, Because my client is sending the recorded voice(the recorded voice what i am sending in bytes format) to ASR engine (Automatic speech recognition).  i am not getting back the same response (i am getting the response audio says "quotation mark") what i send . Client says you are not recording the voice in 16KHz and 16 bit sample rate  thats why you are getting that response.  But i asked him the bytes what i send to his server, He given that .wav file it is playing perfectly. But if the same one he is sending to ASR engine , the ASR engine not accepts the recorded voice what i am sending(He says that ASR wont accept because you are not recording audio in 16KHz and 16 bit sample rate). Client given the following response.  (But, I tried all the ways suggested by you)

```
Filename:   sv_SE_356985580762248932.wav
Folder: E:\developApp\TestappName\Mortionsn_dev\2nd-iteration\test_wfiles
File Type:  44100Hz, 16-bit, Stereo
Uncompressed Size:  1.63 MB (1,713,696 bytes)
File Format:    Windows PCM
Windows PCM
Size on Disk:   1.63 MB (1,717,892 bytes)
Last Written (local):   3/11/2013  00:21:00.000
Length: 0:09.714
428,424 samples
```

**Edit the question 2nd Time By using Below Answers**:

Later by giving the suggestions i changed my settings code to:

```
NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];


[recordSettings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];

[recordSettings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];//8000.0

[recordSettings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

[recordSettings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];

[recordSettings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];

[recordSettings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];

[recordSettings setValue: [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this since you edited it. Both answers below should give you an audio file recorded at 16kHz. Where and how does the client come into this and why do they want 16kHz?

Comment: Yeah as you said both answers are correct.  My Back End Client Said, I want in 16Khz because he is sending that bytes (what we are sending)  to ASR(Automatic Speech Recognisation) engine. My client said that, ASR engine only accept the recorded voice in 16KHz .. Thats why i changed my settings when i record audio  @Robert

Comment: i do not know where the mistake is... is it in our end ? @Robert

Comment: I'm not sure but as far as I can tell, you *will* be sending him 16kHz files so I'd *guess* the error is at the other end.

Comment: ok.....this is my client requirement i.e., "Submits a voice message to Message Queue. Voice file be in format of pcm codec, 16Bit and 16Khz or 16Bit and 8Khz".            Am i satisfied that settings by using the above code.... see my question once.. i edited the question... am i using PCM technique?  and am i satisfied his requirement or not? @Robert

Comment: hey.. r u there.... can u see this once... @Robert

Comment: Again, as far as I can tell, you *are* using PCM and 16Bit. check your file properties to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your existing settings are 44.1kHz and 16 bit so (assuming the above already works) the only line you'd need to change is:

```
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0]
```

To:

```
[NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,
General Audio settings are,

```
AVFormatIDKey,
AVSampleRateKey,
AVNumberOfChannelsKey.
```

And for Audio recorder

```
AVEncoderAudioQualityKey;
AVEncoderBitRateKey;
AVEncoderBitRatePerChannelKey;
AVEncoderBitDepthHintKey;
```

make sure you have included general and recorder settings.

and change your `AVSampleRateKey` to `16000.0`,

```
NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:                 
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM],
                                AVFormatIDKey
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2],
                                AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat:16000.0],
                                AVSampleRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:16],
                                AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                nil];
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for giving the reply... can u please see my edited question once again @Vedchi

Comment: HI, can u please check out my question once again ... i do not know where the mistake is... is it in our end ?   @Vedhic